# Proving an inequality is valid for all values of x?

Tags: inequality

I would appreciate a hint on how to start this problem:

Prove that, for all values of x,  $$x^2+6x+18>2-{1\over 2x}$$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it is not so clear, what you meant

Comment: Please see my edit and confirm or re-edit. Also, you should show your attempts, otherwise the question will most likely be closed.

Comment: are you sure that this is right, from where do you get this?

Comment: Does the exercise perhaps state: For all **positive** values of $x$? Otherwise, if you are asked to prove this is true for all $x\in \mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$, the statement is incorrect.

Comment: If you are asked to prove this for all $x>0$, then obviously $2-\dfrac{1}{2x}<2$ for all $x>0$, therefore you only need to prove that $x^2+6x+18>2$, which is trivial.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's wrong for $x\rightarrow0^-$.

For example, take $x=-0.01.$

Comment: It is wrong for many other values as well.

Comment: Yes, of course, but it's enough to give one counterexample.